# Replacing Axis .jws-file deployment with WSDD deployment without changing the URL (Axis 1)

Tags: web-services, axis

I have an old axis 1 webservice here that is deployed via a MyWebService.jws file. It was called by an URL like this:

> http://localhost:8080/WebApp/service/MyWebService.jws?method=coolMethod

Now I want to replace the jws-file deployment method and use a WSDD file instead, however I would like to keep the URL for the webservice access the same.

Naively I though that I could just replace the service's name with 'MyWebService.jws' like this:

> <service name="MyWebService.jws" provider="java:RPC">
>      <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*" />
>      <parameter name="scope" value="request"/>
>      <parameter name="typeMappingVersion" value="1.1"/>
>      <parameter name="className" value="MyWebServiceClass" />
>   </service>

Sadly that does not work as expected, because Axis recognizes the *.jws* inside the name and handles it like a .jws-file deployment, which now, after the .jws files have been removed obviously leads to this error message:

> <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
>   <faultstring>java.io.FileNotFoundException: /service/MyWebService.jws</faultstring>

Is there a way to stop axis from interpreting a webservice name like 'MyWebService.jws' as a .jws-file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering my own question: this is not possible in Axis, interpreting service names that end with '.jws' as .jws-Files is hardcoded.

In the end, I build myself my own Axis version that uses a different default-ending, allowing me to deploy the webservices as needed.